# Dejar div oculto con jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un problema , necesito dejar un DIV oculto por defecto con jquery y no quiero agregar un boton para mostrarlo, solo quiero dejarlo oculto por defecto sin que se muestre.

Les consulto ya que no tengo mucho idea de javascript o jquery y estaria necesitando esta funcionalidad.

Lo que quiero ocultar es lo siguiente:

```
<td>No<input checked="checked" name="hombre[guardarHombre]" type="radio" value="N" class="checkImporte" id="chekocultt">
```

No quiero usar CSS, ya que necesito hacerlo con javascript / jquery

Tengo lo siguiente al momento:

```
$( document ).ready(function() { $('#chekocultt').hide(); });
```

Comment: Agrega la clase `hide` de Jquery para que el input tenga un `display:block` pero desde Jquery

Comment: Tengo realizado lo siguiente: $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#chekocultt').hide();
    });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intenta esto.

```
<div id="elemento">
    <td>No<input checked="checked" name="hombre[guardarHombre]" type="radio" value="N" class="checkImporte" id="chekocultt">
    </td>
</div>
```

encerré la celda de la tabla en un div, ese div tiene un id que es "elemento".
Ahora en Javascript.

```
ele=document.getElementById("elemento");
ele.style.display="none";
```

- En, **ele=document.getElementById("elemento")** estamos guardando tal elemento, y lo estamos identificando por su ID.
- En, **ele.style.display="none"** estamos aplicando a este elemento un estilo de css sin necesidad de css en nuestro archivo y desde Javascript.

Así evitas usar una hoja de estilos Css, y todo desde Javascript.
Espero y sea de tu ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias tu codigo me sirvio

Comment: Con mucho gusto :)

Answer (score 3):

Tengo este que me funciona:

```
<div id="ErrorAlert" class="" style="display:none" role="alert">
     Error en los datos enviados!
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span>x</span></button>
</div>
```

y desde javascript lo llamo a mostrarse:

```
function Mostrar () {
    $("#ErrorAlert").show();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Considera que lo puedes hacer con JavaSscript puro de este modo:

- Maneja dicho comprtamiento a través de una class en CSS en la cual manejes un **`display: none;`**
- Obtén por medio de su **`id`** el **`div`** y asignalo a una variable
- Agregale un *listener* al `document` para el evento: **`DOMContentLoaded`**
- Dentro de dicho evento agrega a la variable que representa a tu **`div`** la clase con el efecto de ocultamiento declarada en la regla CSS del inicio
- Usa **`classList`** y su método **`add`** para agregar dicha clase

**Propuesta de código**

En **CSS**

```
.oculto {
      display: none;
}
```

En **JavaScript**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      divOculto.classList.add("oculto")
    })
```